# Gii Model generator wont let me to create a Model.(Throws Table 'authors' does not exist)

Tags: yii, yii2, gii

I created a migration for the authors table.

```
public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('authors', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'name' => $this->string()->notNull()
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('authors');
    }
```

After migrating a table,I wanted to make a model for the migration. so Tried creating a model using the gii and this is what i got.
[image]

The table authors has already been created by the migration,but the gii model generator still says Table 'authors' does not exist.
Is there anything else that i am missing?

This is my db.php file

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myFirstYii',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    //'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    //'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    //'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

Comment: Are you sure you have correct database connected? Did you get `author` table name in autocomplete while you enter value in table name field of gii? If above question are true then try clearing gii cache and refresh browser window.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Yes I do have the correct database connected and also have used the autocomplete while entering the value in table name .Any idea how to clear gii cache?

Comment: Yii2 basic or advance template?

Comment: have you checked the table "authors" exist in database "myFirstYii"?

Comment: @InsaneSkull basic template

Comment: @RK12 yes it does exist.

Comment: What does the `getTableNames()` function shows? https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-schema#$tableNames-detail